# Create dataframe from logical test

Tags: r, logical-operators

I've got what I know is a really easy question, but I'm stumped and seem to lack the vocabulary to seek out the answer effectively with the search bar.

I have a data frame full of numbers similar to this (though not of the same class)

```
 Dat <- structure(c(9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 
 10L, 2L, 9L, 0L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 
 1L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 10L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 
 7L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 
 0L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 
 4L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 0L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 
 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L), .Dim = c(10L, 10L
 ))
```

All I want to do is replace all values > 5 with a 1, and all values less than 5 with a 0. I've gotten as far as getting a frame with TRUE and FALSE, but can't seem to figure out how to replace things.

```
 Datlog <- Dat > 5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You mean like `(Dat > 5) * 1`?

Comment: God that's ridiculous. Yes that seems to have worked. Can you explain why/how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you'll kick yourself for the answer:

```
(Dat > 5) * 1
```

`TRUE` and `FALSE` in R equate to `1` and `0` respectively. As such, the more semantically correct way to do this would be something like:

```
out <- as.numeric(Dat > 5)
dim(out) <- dim(Dat)
```

The two step approach is required in this second approach because when you use `as.numeric`, the `dim`s of the original data are lost.

---

One way to replace with different values would be to use `factor`:

```
out <- factor((Dat > 5), c(TRUE, FALSE), c("YES", "NO"))
dim(out) <- dim(Dat)
```

Another way would be basic subsetting and substitution:

```
out <- Dat
out[out > 5] <- 999
out[out <= 5] <- 0
out
```

Comment: Ah, I understand, so 1*1 gives me a 1 and 0*1 gives 0. What if I wanted something other than 1 or 0?

Comment: @user2510207, still just the two ranges? Can you give an example of what you might want to replace them with?

Comment: You've got it covered above. This is extremely helpful, thank you!

Comment: And yet a third way would be to increment the 0/1 value by 1 and use as an index into a character vector:  `c("Low", "High")[1+(out >5)]`